# Couldn't catch new FlutterFire Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to catch exception from the new https://firebase.flutter.dev/ Firebase Auth and failed.
Not sure what went wrong, here is my code for signIn with email and password function:

```
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      if (userCredential != null) {
        _user = userCredential.user;
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return _user;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., {code: wrong-password, additionalData: {}, message: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.}))

Answer (score 0):

Have you check at firebase console authentication whether your user is listed there or not.

[image]

If it not that's the problem, you can add new user at the console and try again login with email and password u just add.

Comment: I can login without problem.
I just want to catch exception when email is not registered or password is wrong.
I have no problem catching exception on previous firebase authentication.

Comment: Oh I see, then you can use catchError method like this: `await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });`

Comment: it couldn't catch the exception but print the error? or the error doesn't print out ?

Comment: it doesn't print out the exception on debug console.
it just throw the exception, causing the app to stop.

Comment: for sure it will stop if it on debug mode, have you try it on release mode?

Comment: to my understanding, app won't stop if the exception is caught properly.
on my other project I use firebase_auth: ^0.16.1, the exception is caught and displayed on the app and debug console. I still can continue the app and fill in the correct password or email.

Comment: I think the problem is in your `UserCredential`, because _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is returning `AuthResult`, try to change it with `AuthResult`.

Comment: I'm just following the documentation from https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage. Just like the sample code given by Shri Hari.
new FirebaseAuth is returning future<UserCredential>. I can't change it to AuthResult.
looks like a dead end at the moment. I've moved on with working on returning data from the firestore. 
I'll try to read the new documentation more. thanks for helping.

Comment: I have the same problem, I couldn't find a solution yet

Comment: I have too. I couldn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

More Error Codes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#error-codes_12